# Key combination for selecting all the text in an edit buffer?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I need combination for selecting all of the text in an edit buffer for an editor like Sublime Text.

On the Windows OSes I would use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>. On OS X this combination seems to moves cursor to beginning of the current line.

So how do I select all the text in the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Hahaha. The answer is simple: it is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>